# Prevent Drag on a specific TTreeNode in a TTreeView?

Tags: delphi, c++builder

With a `TTreeView` setup with `DragMode` `dmAutomatic` I can use the `OnDragDrop` and `OnDragOver` events to handle the drag/drop.   But I don't want a particular `TTreeNode` in the tree to be able to be dragged.   I would guess I would need to use `dmManual` but I haven't found an example of how to do that and wonder if that is what is required?

So the basic question is, how do you prevent a particular `TTreeNode` item from being able to be dragged (it can be a drop target)?  If `dmManual`, how do you use that mode?

TIA!!

Comment: You can prevent dropping some nodes in dragover like this:`Node := TreeView1.Selected;   Accept := (Node <> Nil) and (Node.Text > 'g') ;`

Comment: It's the drag I want to prevent, not the drop.  It will basically be the root (top-most) item that can't be moved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want fully exclude drag start, you have to use `dmManual` mode, as you wrote, and set `BeginDrag` in `OnMouseDown`:

```
if (Button = mbLeft) and 
   (Treeview1.Selected <> nil) and 
   (Treeview1.Selected.Text > 'b') then
        TreeView1.BeginDrag(True);
```

In this example node with `text='aa'` is not dragged, while `node 'cc'` is.

Perhaps sometimes you'll need also change `Immediate` to `False` and apply `Threshold` value (if you need clicks)

Answer (score 1):

In the `OnDragOver` event, you can test if the selected `TTreeNode` is a node you don't want to be dragged, and if so then you can reject the drag. For example:

```
procedure TMyForm.TreeView1DragOver(Sender, Source: TObject;
  X, Y: Integer; State: TDragState; var Accept: Boolean);
var
  Node: TTreeNode;
begin
  Accept := False;
  if Source = TreeView1 then
  begin
    Node := TreeView1.Selected;
    Accept := (Node <> nil) and (Node <> ANodeThatShouldNotBeDragged);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Ah, the opposite way, that will work!   I noticed the "is" for pascal, what do they have for c++ builder if you know? (I have used IsKindOf() in MFC).

Comment: Source is Treeview here, not Node

Comment: @user3161924 the C++ equivalent of `is` is [`dynamic_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast)

Comment: I was hoping it wasn't the slow dynamic_cast, but good to know.